# nginx very high I/O usage on /var/lib/nginx/proxy files

Tags: nginx

My homeserver (running on a Dell low profile machine, 32 GB RAM, quad core CPU) is running 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04.4 with nginx 1.14.0 reverse proxying to a variety of services - Zoneminder, Nextcloud, HomeAssistant, etc - primarily running directly on the server, not in Docker.

Lately (several months), the server has been brought to its knees, reporting load >5 even immediately after a reboot.

Right after boot, I run iotop, I see 3 nginx worker processes pegged at 99% I/O. I used fatrace to try to see what's going on, as the nginx logs aren't reporting much activity that would explain that. These services are being lightly used internally only by family members and my own devices.

fatrace shows endless fast scrolling of the following. I'm not that familiar with fatrace, but I think it's meant to be a live stream, not li

```
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
nginx(2605): W /var/lib/nginx/proxy/9/00/0000000009 (deleted)
```

During this time, nginx logs are showing minimal activity.

EDIT: I am running nginx as the main reverse proxy, and forwarding requests for Nextcloud to Apache, which is hosting Nextcloud. I don't remember why I set it up this way, but I believe Nextcloud didn't recommend nginx at the time, or didn't have a setup guide.

Also, it appears the calls to nextcloud are what trigger this endless nginx  loop. Here's what my nginx configuration for the forwarding to Apache looks like.

```
    location /nextcloud {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81/nextcloud/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
         proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
         proxy_send_timeout 1800;
         send_timeout 1800;
}
```

What are all these (deleted) lines in fatrace and what can I do to prevent nginx eating up all my I/O?

Comment: Better try [SF](https://serverfault.com/) or [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).